# How to check S1000D document for BREX?

Tags: xml-documentation

I develop a small S1000D project (~100 data modules) with BREX module. 
For storage my documents I use file system instead expensive CSDB. 
I need some tool or code example to validate my documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use S1000D 4.0 or 4.1 issues, you can try free tool: [S1000D Checker](http://www.libroplanta.com/en/s1000d-checker).
I don't know any projects with source code.

Comment: This question is very old (and closed as off-topic), but since it still shows up in searches and the linked tool does not appear to be available anymore, I would like to offer an alternative: These [s1kd-tools](https://github.com/kibook/s1kd-tools) are free and open source, are meant to work with a simple "file system"-type CSDB that the question mentions, and include [s1kd-brexcheck](https://github.com/kibook/s1kd-tools/tree/master/tools/s1kd-brexcheck). _Disclaimer:_ I am the author, and they are a work-in-progress.